# SELECT list expression references column integration_start_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm facing an issue with the following query. It gave me this error [SELECT list expression references column integration_start_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [34:63]]. In particular, it points to the first 'when' in the result table, which I don't know how to fix. This is on BigQuery if that helps. I see everything is written correctly or I could be wrong. Seeking for help.

```
with plan_data as (
select format_date("%Y-%m-%d",last_day(date(a.basis_date))) as invoice_date,
        a.sponsor_id as sponsor_id,
        b.company_name as sponsor_name,
        REPLACE(SUBSTR(d.meta,STRPOS(d.meta,'merchant_id')+12,13),'"','') as merchant_id,
        a.state as plan_state,
        date(c.start_date) as plan_start_date,
        a.employee_id as square_employee_id,
        date(
            (select min(date) 
            from glproductionview.stats_sponsors 
            where sponsor_id = a.sponsor_id and sponsor_payroll_provider_identifier = 'square' and date >= c.start_date) )
            as integration_start_date,
        count(distinct a.employee_id) as eligible_pts_count, --pts that are in active plan and have payroll activities (payroll deductions) in the reporting month
from glproductionview.payroll_activities as a
        left join glproductionview.sponsors as b
                on a.sponsor_id = b.id
        left join glproductionview.dc_plans as c
                on a.plan_id = c.id
        left join glproductionview.payroll_connections as d
                on a.sponsor_id = d.sponsor_id and d.provider_identifier = 'rocket' and a.company_id = d.payroll_id
where a.payroll_provider_identifier = 'rocket'
        and format_date("%Y-%m",date(a.basis_date)) = '2021-07'
        and a.amount_cents > 0
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 
order by 2 asc
)

select invoice_date,
  sponsor_id,
  sponsor_name,
  eligible_pts_count,
  case
    when eligible_pts_count <= 5 and date_diff(current_date(),integration_start_date, month) <= 12 then 20
    when eligible_pts_count <= 5 and date_diff(current_date(),integration_start_date, month) > 12 then 15
    when eligible_pts_count > 5 and date_diff(current_date(),integration_start_date, month) <= 12 then count(distinct square_employee_id)*4
    when eligible_pts_count > 5 and date_diff(current_date(),integration_start_date, month) > 12 then count(distinct square_employee_id)*3
    else 0
  end as fees
from plan_data
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: Just to try, can you provide all column names instead of group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and see ?

Comment: I did but the error message is still there